# Netbeans 8.0 debug issue

Tags: java, swing, java-8, netbeans-8

I have been developing a swing gui based application on Netbeans 7.4 with Java 1.6-1.7 and works well with no stability issues at all.

Now, as per requirement of my client, they are interested on migrating the app to Netbeans 8.0 under 1.8 Java.

There arent any issues at all involving the code, but when i deploy the app in debug mode, i get this nasty error which renders the application useless, as it doesnt continues on a stable execution just a few seconds later after the app was started :

"A org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem exception has ocurred"

I paste the complete stacktrace, and cross fingers to see if anybody knows what might be missing or going on.

Thank you.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal starting from ModuleCL@7ff319e[com.app.scripting.ruby] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@4b9cfd2c[org.apache.batik], ModuleCL@7ff319e[com.app.scripting.ruby]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@512524c[org.netbeans.swing.outline], ModuleCL@52159784[org.openide.awt], ModuleCL@32ed515[org.openide.windows], ModuleCL@4ec17086[org.netbeans.modules.options.api], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@2acf57e3, ModuleCL@3118070f[org.openide.io], ModuleCL@45873d93[org.openide.nodes], ModuleCL@3abe744b[org.openide.explorer], ModuleCL@68a69b39[com.app.api]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:289)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:259)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal while loading org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqTroubleshootClassNotFound
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:263)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:187)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationImpl.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.xml.XMLUtil.createDocument(XMLUtil.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesStorage$Writer.getDocument(PreferencesStorage.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.Utils.save(Utils.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.StorageImpl$1.run(StorageImpl.java:342)
    at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:127)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:609)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.StorageImpl$FilesystemTracker.runAtomicAction(StorageImpl.java:635)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.StorageImpl._save(StorageImpl.java:335)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.StorageImpl.save(StorageImpl.java:161)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.api.EditorSettingsStorage.save(EditorSettingsStorage.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl.flushSpi(PreferencesImpl.java:369)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl$1.run(PreferencesImpl.java:410)
Caused: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem: task failed due to
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.schedule(RequestProcessor.java:1464)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl.asyncInvocationOfFlushSpi(PreferencesImpl.java:503)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl.putSpi(PreferencesImpl.java:304)
    at java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.put(AbstractPreferences.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl.put(PreferencesImpl.java:149)
    at java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.putBoolean(AbstractPreferences.java:470)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.preferences.PreferencesImpl.putBoolean(PreferencesImpl.java:218)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction$PreferencesNodeAndListener.setPreferencesValue(AbstractEditorAction.java:778)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction$PreferencesNodeAndListener.propertyChange(AbstractEditorAction.java:794)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(SwingPropertyChangeSupport.java:92)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at javax.swing.AbstractAction.firePropertyChange(AbstractAction.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction.putValue(AbstractEditorAction.java:613)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction$PreferencesNodeAndListener.<init>(AbstractEditorAction.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction.checkPreferencesKey(AbstractEditorAction.java:707)
    at org.netbeans.spi.editor.AbstractEditorAction.<init>(AbstractEditorAction.java:325)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.actions.WrapperEditorAction.<init>(WrapperEditorAction.java:71)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.actions.WrapperEditorAction.create(WrapperEditorAction.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS$AttrImpl$MethodAndParams.invoke(BinaryFS.java:773)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS$AttrImpl.getValue(BinaryFS.java:703)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS$BFSBase.getAttribute(BinaryFS.java:549)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getAttribute(MultiFileObject.java:944)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getAttribute(MultiFileObject.java:877)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getAttribute(MultiFileObject.java:940)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getAttribute(MultiFileObject.java:877)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getAttribute(MultiFileObject.java:798)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject$Ser.instanceCreate(InstanceDataObject.java:1432)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject.instanceCreate(InstanceDataObject.java:846)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.ActionsList.convertImpl(ActionsList.java:147)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.ActionsList.<init>(ActionsList.java:85)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.EditorActionsProvider.<init>(EditorActionsProvider.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.EditorActionsProvider.createInstance(EditorActionsProvider.java:88)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.EditorActionsProvider.createInstance(EditorActionsProvider.java:62)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl.InstanceProviderLookup.rebuild(InstanceProviderLookup.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl.InstanceProviderLookup.initialize(InstanceProviderLookup.java:85)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.enterStorage(AbstractLookup.java:176)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.lookupItem(AbstractLookup.java:430)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.lookup(AbstractLookup.java:421)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup.lookup(ProxyLookup.java:222)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl.SwitchLookup.lookup(SwitchLookup.java:90)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup.lookup(ProxyLookup.java:222)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.impl.EditorActionsProvider.getEditorActions(EditorActionsProvider.java:69)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorKit.getDeclaredActions(NbEditorKit.java:220)
    at org.netbeans.editor.BaseKit.addActionsToMap(BaseKit.java:952)
    at org.netbeans.editor.BaseKit.getActions(BaseKit.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.keymap.EditorBridge.initActionMap(EditorBridge.java:358)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.keymap.EditorBridge.getEditorActionsMap(EditorBridge.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.keymap.EditorBridge.getActions(EditorBridge.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.KeymapModel$AL.run(KeymapModel.java:203)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.KeymapModel.waitFinished(KeymapModel.java:768)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.KeymapModel.ensureActionsLoaded(KeymapModel.java:739)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.KeymapModel.isDuplicateId(KeymapModel.java:390)
    at org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.ShortcutsFinderImpl.findActionForId(ShortcutsFinderImpl.java:99)
    at org.netbeans.core.options.keymap.api.KeyStrokeUtils.getKeyStrokesForAction(KeyStrokeUtils.java:241)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutputTab$TabAction.getAcceleratorsFor(OutputTab.java:1013)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutputTab$TabAction.<init>(OutputTab.java:963)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutputTab.createActions(OutputTab.java:916)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutputTab.access$300(OutputTab.java:117)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutputTab$2.run(OutputTab.java:838)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Comment: Is required jar `batik-ext.jar` present in the class-path?

Comment: Yes, its present in the class-path.

Comment: It is present in the classpath and was added for such reason into a Wrapper. But no clue why this error is happening